# Como adicionar um icon em cada extremo de um EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

Quero adicionar dois icones ao EditText do android de acordo com a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código que já utilizei para adicionar a imagem ao lado direito.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_enter" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_line">

            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Para colocar as duas imagens no EditText como devo proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu defini no próprio EditText, na propriedade `android:drawableRight`.
Você pode fazer desse jeito também:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edt_mc_locproduto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:hint="@string/lbl_loc_produto"
     android:inputType="textCapSentences"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_mi_pesquisar"
     android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
     android:imeActionLabel="Search"/>
```

Comment: Essa é a maneira correta de resolver o problema do autor da pergunta.

Comment: Resolvi desta maneira, utilizando os dois elemento drawableLeft e drawableRight.
**android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_cadeado_little"**
**android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon_enter_little"**

Answer (score 1):

Pegando no seu xml será assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

No entanto as imagens ficam por cima do EditText.

Se não é isso que pretende use um LinearLayout com orientação horizontal, colocando o EditText entre as duas imagens.

No EditText use `android:layout_width="0dp"` e `android:layout_weight="1"` para que ele tenha um comprimento igual a todo a largura disponível entre as imagens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

     <EditText
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Nota:** Substitua `@mipmap/ic_launcher`pelos drawables das suas imagens.